# Error in libcrypto connecting RHEL 9 server to Centos 6 via SFTP/SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, openssl, sftp, rhel9

I am trying to connect from a new RHEL9 server to an older Centos 6 server to SFTP files from the older server to the new one for an upgrade, but when connecting from 9 to 6 I get the following error:

```
[ewessel@ftp ~]$ ssh -v ewessel@10.30.1.250
OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Connecting to 10.30.1.250 [10.30.1.250] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug1: Authenticating to 10.30.1.250:22 as 'ewessel'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ewessel/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nMDl3BNpsOOJ6gyMudi6szQS3Pchxe2Ttmj1dH9fLB8
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/ewessel/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '10.30.1.250' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ewessel/.ssh/known_hosts:1
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.30.1.250 port 22: error in libcrypto
```

if I try connecting the other way I get the following error:

```
[ewessel@ftp ~]$ ssh -v ewessel@10.30.1.225
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.30.1.225 [10.30.1.225] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ewessel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
no hostkey alg
```

Any idea on how to get these 2 machines to talk to each other?  I'd like to copy the user files from the old machine to the new so I can decommission the old Centos 6 machine.

Answer (score 6):

RHEL 9 defaults to stronger cryptographic ciphers and algorithms, breaking compatibility with legacy systems.

Your options for the SSH daemon on the RHEL 9 system are:

- Switch the system-wide cryptographic policy to a mode compatible with earlier releases as described in the [RHEL 9 hardening guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening#switching-the-system-wide-crypto-policy-to-mode-compatible-with-previous-systems_using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies).  As `root` (or with `sudo`) run:

  ```
  # update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
  Setting system policy to LEGACY
  ```

  and reboot.

  **Note:** this changes *all* daemons and system settings and is a bit overkill if you only need to adjust the settings for ssh and sshd.
- Exclude (only) sshd from the system-wide cryptographic policy. You opt-out by editing `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` and uncommenting the line `# CRYPTO_POLICY=` , (if necessary you can then adjust adjust `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add legacy crypto settings) and restart the ssh daemon.

For the ssh command line client on the RHEL 9 system: you're recommended to edit `˜/.ssh/config` and override the modern/secure system wide ssh client defaults by adding a Host entry that adds support for suitable legacy encryption options for that particular host:

```
#    ˜/.ssh/config

Host rhel6.example.com
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  MACs +hmac-sha1
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 3):

Adding my two cents, if you don't want to modify the system-wide cryptographic policy which may downgrade security for the whole system.

Then, you need to create a file `/var/tmp/openssl.cnf` with:

```
.include /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
[openssl_init]
alg_section = evp_properties
[evp_properties]
rh-allow-sha1-signatures = yes
```

Now you can SSH to RHEL 5 or RHEL 6 hosts like this:

```
OPENSSL_CONF=/var/tmp/openssl.cnf ssh rhel5or6-host
```

This is necesary because RHEL 9 also maims the openssl library by disabling SHA1 support. That is why editing your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/01-crypto-policy-override.conf` or `~/.ssh/config` is not enough.

Btw, this is not mine. This is the original post, [SSH from RHEL 9 to RHEL 5 or RHEL 6](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2022/08/08/ssh-from-rhel-9-to-rhel-5-or-rhel-6/). There is also a request to make this more modular so you can control crypto policies for applications instead of system-wide, here is the [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2064740).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in the same issue, and the answers above did solve the issue for me. With those ssh settings the initial handshake was established, but ssh kept failing with

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.121.188 port 22: error in libcrypto
```

In the end what fixed the issue for me was changing the general "crypto policy" of EL9, using

```
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Note that the command above changes lots of other things in addition to ssh client, so you may want to check the [manual of update-crypto-policies](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening#switching-the-system-wide-crypto-policy-to-mode-compatible-with-previous-systems_using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies) and choose a more selective option.

Answer (score -1):

To help resolve the error you encountered while connecting from a new RHEL9 server to an older CentOS 6 server for SFTP file transfer, follow these steps:
Create a configuration file named "config" inside the ~/.ssh directory. The file should have no extension. You can use the command touch config to create it.
Open the "config" file using a text editor of your choice, such as Vim, Vi, or Nano.
Paste the following code into the "config" file:enter code here
enter code here

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
Host rhel9.example.com
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  MACs +hmac-sha1
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Save the file after pasting the code.
Restart the SSH server, either by restarting the sshd service or by rebooting the server. The exact method may vary depending on the distribution you are using.
By following these steps, you should be able to eliminate the error you encountered while connecting to the CentOS 6 server. This configuration is also useful when connecting to a Cisco router via SSH.

Comment: IMHO there are several things wrong here: the first two lines in your proposed  `~/.ssh/config` above the `Host` line set the default for *all hosts* rather than for only a specific host and are not needed . A ~/.ssh/config  adjusts settings for the ssh/sftp/scp ***client*** and any changes there are picked immediately the next time you launch the client.  Changing client settings  does *not* require restarting the ssh ***daemon*** , let alone rebooting the server!