# Connection reset by 10.180.20.1 port 22

Tags: ssh, centos7, cisco

Using a CentOS 7.9.2009 server I'm trying to ssh v1 using client with v2 into a Cisco router that has SSH v1 (can't be upgraded, I'm anticipating that).
I then modified my ssh_config file to allow for the v1 version of ssh by changing the value of the #Protocol 2 line to Protocol 2,1.

When I try to connect but I get this error that is not speaking:

```
ssh test@10.180.20.1 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.180.20.1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.180.20.1 [10.180.20.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/audit/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.5, remote software version Cisco-1.25
debug1: match: Cisco-1.25 pat Cisco-1.* compat 0x60000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-1.5-OpenSSH_7.4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.180.20.1:22 as 'test'
debug1: Waiting for server public key.
Connection reset by 10.180.20.1 port 22
```

If anyone has ideas on what kind of troubleshooting to do to figure out where the problem is, thank you in advance. At the moment keep in mind that I don't have access to that router I can do the tests on the CentOS machine to which I have access.

I also tried to connect specifying the version v1: `ssh -v1 test@10.180.20.1 -vvv`

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. In general:

Debugging server issues is not (only) done from the client side. Don't only report on client-side issues  (the `ssh -vvv` output), also show relevant server configuration & settings, server log and/or error messages. In other words : *"what is your Cisco device telling you?"*

A random manual from Cisco https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/secure-shell-ssh/4145-ssh.html

Suggests `show ssh` , `show ip ssh` and `show crypto key mypubkey rsa` as first debugging steps on the router.

When you say: *"I then modified my ssh_config file"*  I wonder why you change the global configuration `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` rather than not making any modifications in your personal `~/ssh/config` which would be the typical thing to do.

```
#    For example ˜/.ssh/config
#  Use custom settings when connecting to 10.180.20.1 from: https://serverfault.com/a/1125849/37681

Host 10.180.20.1
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  MACs +hmac-sha1
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  Protocol 2,1
```

---

I ***guess*** the fact that your client b0rks after:

> `debug1: Waiting for server public key.`

is the relevant debug message: that suggests that your client isn't receiving a server public key.

My first guess is that you omitted to properly configure the Cisco device and didn't generate the proper ssh keys.