# Changes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config not working

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to disable SHA1...  I changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config to reflect this:

```
# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none
Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
```

Yet after restarting the server and\or running `systemctl restart sshd`, I get this:

```
sshd -T | grep kex
gssapikexalgorithms gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without more context difficult to say but on for example RHEL 9 by default the system wide crypto-policy overrules what you set in sshd_config https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening and https://serverfault.com/q/1125843/37681

Comment: What additional context are you looking for?  This is openssh-server.x86_64 8.7pl-34.e19 running on Rocky Linux 9.  I'm trying to disable SHA1

Comment: Rocky 9 is the context, that is RHEL clone and that makes my initial educated guess that your problems are the result of a security policy much more probable. The links should help you to either determine or change the system security policy or override that for sshd

Answer (score 2):

Solutions was to run:

```
update-crypto-policies --set FUTURE
```

And to restart the server.  Thanks, [HBruijn](https://serverfault.com/users/37681/hbruijn)!